# How to add a Panel to SplitContainer?

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

I am using SplitContainer and it contains only 2 panels but I need 3(panels).

**QUESTIONS:**

Is it possible to add more panels to SplitContainer?

```
if YES
      how? 
else
      why not?
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it's not possible. But, you could always use a second `SplitContainer` in one of the first `SplitContainer`'s panel to obtain similar results.

Comment: It's an easy and quick solution, but you have to take into account that resizing the 'outer' Splitcontainer's splitter, results in a location shift of the 'inner' Splitcontainer's splitter as well.

Comment: @Xilconic: If that is not the intended behaviour you can always set the FixedPanel of the inner split container to Panel1.

Comment: The comments actually have the interesting part of the answer, if you're trying to have two side panels and a central area that changes size when the panels are adjusted. Add a SplitContainer, then put a second SplitContainer in the right panel of the first. Select the second SplitContainer, and set Layout > FixedPanel to Panel2. Now, changing the size of the left panel doesn't change the size of the right panel.

Answer (score 0):

As specified earlier, yes you can use a second split or add 2 panels to the panel in question.